# Fetching Data from SQLite Database in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Here I'm fetching data from SQLite in android but issue is there are total 20 columns in database  its fetch 19 column correctly but when I fetch last 20th column the whole array[] is empty

For example 
when I write Query

```
SELECT NEW_ANIMAL_ID,TAG_NO,FARMER_ID,ANIMAL_EAR_POSITION,ANIMAL_SPECIES,ANIMAL_BREED,ANIMAL_BODY_COLOR,ANIMAL_SHAPE_RIGHT,ANIMAL_SHAPE_LEFT,ANIMAL_SWITCH_OF_TAIL,AGE_YEARS,ANIMAL_OTHER_MARKS,PRAG_STATUS,NUMBER_OF_LACTATION,CURRENT_MILK,SUM_INSURED,TAG_IMAGE,HEAD_IMAGE,LEFT_SIDE_IMAGE,RIGHT_SIDE_IMAGE  FROM  ANIMAL_SYNC_TABLE    ORDER BY  NEW_ANIMAL_ID   DESC
```

its fetch 19 column completly

but when I added last column name and try to fetch it shows an empty array[]

```
Query = SELECT NEW_ANIMAL_ID,TAG_NO,FARMER_ID,ANIMAL_EAR_POSITION,ANIMAL_SPECIES,ANIMAL_BREED,ANIMAL_BODY_COLOR,ANIMAL_SHAPE_RIGHT,ANIMAL_SHAPE_LEFT,ANIMAL_SWITCH_OF_TAIL,AGE_YEARS,ANIMAL_OTHER_MARKS,PRAG_STATUS,NUMBER_OF_LACTATION,CURRENT_MILK,SUM_INSURED,TAG_IMAGE,HEAD_IMAGE,LEFT_SIDE_IMAGE,RIGHT_SIDE_IMAGE,TAIL_IMAGE_1  FROM  ANIMAL_SYNC_TABLE    ORDER BY  NEW_ANIMAL_ID   DESC
```

Here is Create Table Code

```
db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME_ANIMAL_SYNC + "(NEW_ANIMAL_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,FARMER_ID INT,TAG_NO TEXT,ANIMAL_EAR_POSITION TEXT,ANIMAL_SPECIES TEXT,ANIMAL_BREED TEXT,ANIMAL_BODY_COLOR TEXT,ANIMAL_SHAPE_RIGHT TEXT,ANIMAL_SHAPE_LEFT TEXT,ANIMAL_SWITCH_OF_TAIL TEXT,AGE_YEARS NUMBER,ANIMAL_OTHER_MARKS NUMBER,PRAG_STATUS NUMBER,NUMBER_OF_LACTATION NUMBER,CURRENT_MILK NUMBER,SUM_INSURED NUMBER,TAG_IMAGE BLOB NOT NULL,HEAD_IMAGE BLOB NOT NULL,LEFT_SIDE_IMAGE BLOB NOT NULL,RIGHT_SIDE_IMAGE BLOB NOT NULL,TAIL_IMAGE_1 BLOB NOT NULL)");
```

Here is Database Code

```
 public List<DataModel> getAllData() {
        List<DataModel> data = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT NEW_ANIMAL_ID,TAG_NO,FARMER_ID,ANIMAL_EAR_POSITION,ANIMAL_SPECIES,ANIMAL_BREED,ANIMAL_BODY_COLOR,ANIMAL_SHAPE_RIGHT,ANIMAL_SHAPE_LEFT,ANIMAL_SWITCH_OF_TAIL,AGE_YEARS,ANIMAL_OTHER_MARKS,PRAG_STATUS,NUMBER_OF_LACTATION,CURRENT_MILK,SUM_INSURED,TAG_IMAGE,HEAD_IMAGE,LEFT_SIDE_IMAGE,RIGHT_SIDE_IMAGE,TAIL_IMAGE_1  FROM  ANIMAL_SYNC_TABLE    ORDER BY  NEW_ANIMAL_ID   DESC", null);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        DataModel dataModel = null;

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                dataModel = new DataModel();


                int NEW_ANIMAL_ID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NEW_ANIMAL_ID"));
                String TAG_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TAG_NO"));
                String FARMER_ID_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("FARMER_ID"));
                String ANIMAL_EAR_POSITION_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ANIMAL_EAR_POSITION"));
                String ANIMAL_SPECIES_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ANIMAL_SPECIES"));
                String ANIMAL_BREED_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ANIMAL_BREED"));
                String ANIMAL_BODY_COLOR_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ANIMAL_BODY_COLOR"));
                String ANIMAL_SHAPE_RIGHT_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ANIMAL_SHAPE_RIGHT"));
                String ANIMAL_SHAPE_LEFT_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ANIMAL_SHAPE_LEFT"));
                String ANIMAL_SWITCH_OF_TAIL_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ANIMAL_SWITCH_OF_TAIL"));
                String AGE_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("AGE_YEARS"));
                String ANIMAL_OTHER_MARKS_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ANIMAL_OTHER_MARKS"));
                String PRAG_STATUS_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("PRAG_STATUS"));
                String NUMBER_OF_LACTATION_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NUMBER_OF_LACTATION"));
                String CURRENT_MILK_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("CURRENT_MILK"));
                String SUM_INSURED_COLUMN_1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("SUM_INSURED"));


                dataModel.setAnimal_id(NEW_ANIMAL_ID);
                dataModel.setFarmer_id(FARMER_ID_1);
                dataModel.setTag_no(TAG_COLUMN_1);
                dataModel.setEar_position(ANIMAL_EAR_POSITION_COLUMN_1);
                dataModel.setAnimal_species(ANIMAL_SPECIES_COLUMN_1);
                dataModel.setAnimal_breed(ANIMAL_BREED_COLUMN_1);
                dataModel.setBody_color(ANIMAL_BODY_COLOR_COLUMN_1);
                dataModel.setShape_right(ANIMAL_SHAPE_RIGHT_COLUMN_1);
                dataModel.setShape_left(ANIMAL_SHAPE_LEFT_COLUMN_1);
                dataModel.setTail_switch(ANIMAL_SWITCH_OF_TAIL_COLUMN_1);
                dataModel.setAge(AGE_COLUMN_1);
                dataModel.setOther_marks(ANIMAL_OTHER_MARKS_COLUMN_1);
                dataModel.setPrag_status(PRAG_STATUS_COLUMN_1);
                dataModel.setLactations(NUMBER_OF_LACTATION_COLUMN_1);
                dataModel.setMilk_qty(CURRENT_MILK_COLUMN_1);
                dataModel.setSum_insured(SUM_INSURED_COLUMN_1);
                dataModel.setTag_photo(Utils.getBitmapFromByte(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("TAG_IMAGE"))));
                dataModel.setHead_photo(Utils.getBitmapFromByte(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("HEAD_IMAGE"))));
                dataModel.setLeft_photo(Utils.getBitmapFromByte(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("LEFT_SIDE_IMAGE"))));
                dataModel.setRight_photo(Utils.getBitmapFromByte(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("RIGHT_SIDE_IMAGE"))));
                dataModel.setSwitch_Tail_Photo(Utils.getBitmapFromByte(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("TAIL_IMAGE_1"))));


                stringBuffer.append(dataModel);
                data.add(dataModel);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }

        return data;
    }
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Any error in logs ? Have you added that column later ? If yes then uninstall the build and reinstall it .

Comment: Use this SELECT *FROM  ANIMAL_SYNC_TABLE    ORDER BY  NEW_ANIMAL_ID   DESC

Comment: no that column added with all column

Comment: @MohammadAsheri empty Array[]

Comment: Log this value cursor.getCount(); and check how many records cursor containing?

Comment: Log.e("value", cursor.getCount() + "");

E/value: 2 @SurajVaishnav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will you change your code from:

```
 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                dataModel = new DataModel();
               ....
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
```

to this:

```
while(cursor.moveToNext())
{
  dataModel = new DataModel();
  ...

  data.add(dataModel);
}
```

Comment: Log : for (DataModel mo : data) {

            Log.e("DataModel", ""  + mo.getSwitch_Tail_Photo());
        }

E/data: [ ]

Comment: Can you post the code where you created the database?

Comment: Code Updated @MRah

Comment: what are you storing in getSwitch_Tail_Photo add your DataModel class code

Comment: TAIL_IMAGE_1 in getSwitch_Tail_Photo to check its fetching image  or not   @SurajVaishnav

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to this

```
SELECT * FROM ANIMAL_SYNC_TABLE ORDER BY NEW_ANIMAL_ID DESC
```

than check if problem still exist than downlaod app from this link and open your database 
 in this app in your pc
 their fire your query in execute sql tab and check query is proper or not

[https://sqlitebrowser.org/]

Comment: http://sqliteviewer.flowsoft7.com/

I'm using this to check SQL Query but  its working fine but issue in only android  code

Comment: can you sent me your db file "sejpalpavan@gmail.com"

Comment: mail sent bro and thnks

Comment: yes query is proper make sure you have latest copy of your database in assets folder and key name is proper in function where you fetching data

Comment: ya brother everything is updated but still not getting solution or issue what exctly going wrong in code

Comment: problem is data type is string and you try to fetch as blob so it will  not return value,make data type proper first ,put your if(cursor.movetofirst()) into try catch block and catch exception in log

Answer (score 0):

The SQLITE database has limited support for large binary objects (BLOBS). There's a limitation of 1 megabyte for each row of data, and the database uses NUL bytes to separate columns in the storage. ... Contains a reference to a separate blob table.